# Ajax: many (smaller) calls vs. a single large call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a page that will display all available data of a certain kind to all users.  The data will be displayed separated by a number of criteria and I'm pondering certain design questions.

to make matters easier to understand, say I have sales data per month, per category and per location.  on the page I will create an accordion for each month, within which I will have 1 table per category and in each table a list of locations.

so I'm wondering, which is better:

1) a single controller method that fetches all the data and:
   a) does the work of converting the tabular format returned from the database to a hierarchical structure (because this is easier for the front-end to navigate) like:

```
{ Month, { Category, { Location, Value } } }
```

b) returns tabular data like

```
{ Month, Category, Location, Value }
```

and lets JQuery at the front end loop through to make it hierarchical

2) many smaller methods that each return distinct data and that need to be called by the front end? for example, a method that returns a distinct list of months for which there is data would be called once but JQuery would then need to loop through the results to query for the categories, which themselves would be looped through to get locations, sort of like this:

```
  for (var m in GetMonths()) {
     for (var c in GetCategories(m)) {
        GetLocations(m, c);
        }
     }
```

as a final note, by "better" I mean both that the system will perform better under a heavy load, and that the code is structured in a more maintainable and DRY manner.

thank you for your consideration

Answer (score 0):

Without actual performance numbers for the individual queries the answer will have to contain quite a bit of conjecture.  But here are some generalizations.

If the data is being presented to "all users", then your most important decision is going to be cache the data.  Having said that, the server side performance of the code will be much less important.  Not unimportant, but if you're going to server it hundreds, thousands or millions of times for each time it is generated, you can tolerate a little more server-side work.

For scalability, prefer fewer calls to the server over more calls.  That would point to the single controller method that returns all the data.  Unless fetching the data is dramatically more time consuming that fetching just a single month of data, that would be your better choice.

For transforming the data to the hierarchy on the server vs. on the client, I tend to prefer to do it on the client.  If there is a lot of this data, your client experience may be better if it is done on the server but doing it on the client has a could of advantages.  First, client side code is automatically distributed.  If you are trying to get the highest throughput, moving logic, especially presentation logic, to the client will free up the servers to do other work. 
Also, by doing the transformation on the client, your server method is not as dependent on the the view.  If you later decide that a different display would be better, it may just be a view change.

But, back to the beginning of the answer, if you are going to create this data once and cache it, doing the transformation at the server eliminates the need for each client to transform it.